# STL List Implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, deque

I've implemented a C++ STL list for practice purpose (obviously all constructors & methods aren't there). Most of the functions are working properly.

```
#ifndef list_H
#define list_H

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename T>
class list {
public:
    list <T> & operator = (const list<T> &);
    ~list();
    /* Modifiers */
    void push_back(T&& data);
    void push_back(T const& data);
    void push_front(T&& data);
    void push_front(T const& data);
    void pop_back();
    void pop_front();
    void swap(list &x);
    void clear();

    /* Iterators */
    typedef T* iterator;
    typedef T* const const_iterator;

    const_iterator begin() const; // cbegin
    iterator begin();

    const_iterator end() const; //cend()
    iterator end();

    const_iterator rbegin() const;
    iterator rbegin();

    const_iterator rend() const;
    iterator rend();

    /* Capacity */
    size_t size() const;
    bool empty() const;

    /* Element Access */
    T& front();
    T const& front() const;

    T& back();
    T const& back() const;

    T& at(T const indx);
    T const& at(T const indx) const;

    T& operator[] (T const indx);
    T const& operator[] (T const indx) const;

private:
    struct node {
        int data;
        node *next, *prev;
        node(T const& data, node* next, node* prev)
            : data(data)
            , next(next)
            , prev(prev) {
        }
        node(T&& data, node* next, node* prev)
            : data(std::move(data))
            , next(next)
            , prev(prev) {
        }
    };
    int elements = 0;
    node *head = nullptr;
    node *tail = nullptr;
};

template <typename T>
list <T> & list<T>::operator = (const list<T> & that) {
    node* tmp = head;
    while(head) {
        tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete tmp;
    }
    elements = that.elements;
    head = that.head;
    tail = that.tail;
}

template <typename T>
list <T>::~list() {
    node* tmp;
    while(head) {
        tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete tmp;
    }
}


template <typename T>
T& list<T>:: front() {
    if(head == nullptr)
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid Action!");
    return head->data;
}

template <typename T>
T const& list<T>:: front() const {
    if(head == nullptr)
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid Action!");
    return head->data;
}

template <typename T>
T& list<T>:: back() {
    if(tail == nullptr)
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid Action!");
    return tail->data;
}

template <typename T>
T const& list<T>:: back() const {
    if(tail == nullptr)
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid Action!");
    return tail->data;
}

template <typename T>
void list<T>::push_back(T const& data) {
    node* newNode = new node(data, nullptr, tail);
    if(head == nullptr)
        head = newNode;
    if(tail != nullptr)
        tail->next = newNode;
    tail = newNode;
    ++elements;
}

template <typename T>
void list<T>::push_back(T&& data) {
    node* newNode = new node(std::move(data), nullptr, tail);
    if(head == nullptr)
        head = newNode;
    if(tail != nullptr)
        tail->next = newNode;
    tail = newNode;
    ++elements;
}

template <typename T>
void list<T>::push_front(T const& data) {
    node* newNode = new node(data, head, nullptr);
    if(tail == nullptr)
        tail = newNode;
    if(head != nullptr)
        head->prev = newNode;
    head = newNode;
    ++elements;
}

template <typename T>
void list<T>::push_front(T&& data) {
    node* newNode = new node(data, head, nullptr);
    if(tail == nullptr)
        tail = newNode;
    if(head != nullptr)
        head->prev = newNode;
    head = newNode;
    ++elements;
}

template <typename T>
void list<T>::pop_front() {
    if(head == nullptr)
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid Action");
    node *tmp = head;
    head = head->next;
    if(head != nullptr)
        head->prev = nullptr;
    --elements;
    delete tmp;
}

template <typename T>
void list<T>::pop_back() {
    if(tail == nullptr)
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid Action");
    node *tmp = tail;
    tail = tail->prev;
    if(tail != nullptr)
        tail->next = nullptr;
    --elements;
    delete tmp;
}

template <typename T>
bool list<T>::empty() const {
    return head == nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
size_t list<T>::size() const {
    return elements;
}

template <typename T>
T& list<T>::operator[] (T const indx) {
    int cont = 0;
    node *curr = head;
    while(curr) {
        if(cont == indx)
            return curr->data;
        curr = curr->next;
        ++cont;
    }
    return nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
T const& list<T>::operator[] (T const indx) const {
    int cont = 0;
    node *curr = head;
    while(curr) {
        if(cont == indx)
            return curr->data;
        curr = curr->next;
        ++cont;
    }
    return nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
T& list<T>::at(T const indx) {
    int cont = 0;
    node *curr = head;
    while(curr) {
        if(cont == indx)
            return curr->data;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    return nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
T const& list<T>::at(T const indx) const {
    int cont = 0;
    node *curr = head;
    while(curr) {
        if(cont == indx)
            return curr->data;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    return nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
typename list<T>::const_iterator list<T>::begin() const {
    return head;
}

template <typename T>
typename list<T>::iterator list<T>::begin() {
    return head;
}


template <typename T>
typename list<T>::const_iterator list<T>::end() const {
    return tail;
}

template <typename T>
typename list<T>::const_iterator list<T>::rbegin() const {
    return tail;
}
template <typename T>
typename list<T>::iterator list<T>::rbegin() {
    return tail;
}
template <typename T>
typename list<T>::const_iterator list<T>::rend() const {
    return head;
}

template <typename T>
typename list<T>::iterator list<T>::rend() {
    return head;
}

template <typename T>
typename list<T>::iterator list<T>::end() {
    return tail;
}

template <typename T>
void list<T>::swap(list &that) {
    std::swap(head, that.head);
    std::swap(tail, that.tail);
    std::swap(elements, that.elements);
}

template <typename T>
void list<T>::clear() {
    node* curr = head;
    while(head) {
        curr = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete curr;
    }
    head = tail = nullptr;
    elements = 0;
}

#endif // list_H
```

Then I tested this program by:

```
int main(void) {
    deque<int> dq;
    dq.push_back(1);
    dq.push_back(2);
    dq.push_back(3);
    while(!dq.empty()) {
        int value = dq.back();
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
        dq.pop_back();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Well, output is:

```
3
2 
1
```

***But the program isn't terminating in my code::blocks***.

Then I compiled it with Ideone and the output is:

```
3
2
1
    *** Error in `./prog': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x08923008 ***
    ======= Backtrace: =========
    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x75e72)[0xb75f8e72]
    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x76bb0)[0xb75f9bb0]
    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdlPv+0x1f)[0xb77db82f]
    ./prog[0x8048a17]
    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0xb759c8f5]
    ./prog[0x8048b41]
    ======= Memory map: ========
    08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 09:03 16269491   /home/TKjJyD/prog
    08049000-0804a000 rw-p 00001000 09:03 16269491   /home/TKjJyD/prog
    08923000-08944000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
    b7581000-b7583000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    b7583000-b772c000 r-xp 00000000 09:03 16394299   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc-2.17.so
    b772c000-b772d000 ---p 001a9000 09:03 16394299   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc-2.17.so
    b772d000-b772f000 r--p 001a9000 09:03 16394299   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc-2.17.so
    b772f000-b7730000 rw-p 001ab000 09:03 16394299   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc-2.17.so
    b7730000-b7733000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    b7733000-b774e000 r-xp 00000000 09:03 16394343   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
    b774e000-b774f000 rw-p 0001a000 09:03 16394343   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
    b774f000-b7750000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    b7750000-b7791000 r-xp 00000000 09:03 16394296   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libm-2.17.so
    b7791000-b7792000 r--p 00040000 09:03 16394296   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libm-2.17.so
    b7792000-b7793000 rw-p 00041000 09:03 16394296   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libm-2.17.so
    b7793000-b786f000 r-xp 00000000 09:03 16679929   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.18
    b786f000-b7870000 ---p 000dc000 09:03 16679929   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.18
    b7870000-b7874000 r--p 000dc000 09:03 16679929   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.18
    b7874000-b7875000 rw-p 000e0000 09:03 16679929   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.18
    b7875000-b787c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    b787e000-b7882000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    b7882000-b7883000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
    b7883000-b78a2000 r-xp 00000000 09:03 16394256   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
    b78a2000-b78a3000 r--p 0001f000 09:03 16394256   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
    b78a3000-b78a4000 rw-p 00020000 09:03 16394256   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
    bfa1b000-bfa3c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
```

I think the problem is in `pop_back()` function. Can anyone know what happened?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Compile with optimisations disabled, and debug symbols enabled (e.g. `g++ -Wall -O0 -g ...`) and then run your code under a debugger (e.g. `gdb`).

Comment: Try output the `size` in the loop as well.

Comment: Not the answer, but in your node struct, you set int directly instead of the typename T

Comment: @Geoffroy Thanks! I didn't notice, very bad mistake!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`pop_back` needs to nullify `head` if the list becomes empty; otherwise, the destructor will use the dangling `head` pointer to try to delete the already deleted nodes.

There's also a problem with the assignment operator: it makes a "shallow copy" of the other list's pointers, so that both lists will think they own (and try to delete) the same nodes.

(Also, this is closer to `list` than `deque`. A deque is supposed to allow random access in constant time; a linked-list implementation won't allow that.)

Comment: Yes, I've discovered now the termination problem is due to `pop_back`. Because I commented the destructor code and let the compiler to call default constructor. And the program terminates.

Comment: You said "A deque is supposed to allow random access in constant time". Do you have any reference? I know it should allow random access, but never saw anything about the constant time

Comment: @Geoffroy: C++11, 23.2.3/16: "An implementation shall provide these operations for all container types shown in the “container” column, and shall implement them so as to take amortized constant time.", where "these operations" are the optional operations listed in table 100, including random access via `[]` and `at` for containers including `deque`.

Comment: @Geoffroy: Or, if you literally mean STL, not the modern standard library, the complexity requirement for random access is documented [here](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/RandomAccessContainer.html).

Comment: @MikeSeymour I meant the modern standard library, and thanks for the precision!